# Добавление элемента в листинг

Tags: java, android

Есть такой класс

```
class Info {
String one, two, three;}
```

И есть динамический листинг

```
private ArrayList <Info> info = new ArrayList <Info> ();
```

И сейчас, чтобы добавить новый элемент массива я использую метод дилетанта

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    int i = info.size ();

    info.add (new Info ());
    info.get (i).one = "one";
    info.get (i).two = "two";
    info.get (i).three = "three";
}
```

И я хотел узнать, как в java немного видоизменить этот код?
Когда я работал с C#, на сколько я помню, такая операция делалась подобным образом

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    info.add (new Info () {
        one = "one";
        two = "two";
        three = "three";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На java у вас есть несколько вариантов.

1. Без изменения класса `Info`:

```java
public void onClick (View v) {
    Info i = new Info();
    i.one = "one";
    i.two = "two";
    i.three = "three";
    info.add(i);
}
```

2. в том же стиле, только с сеттерами.
3. Добавляем конструктор:

```
class Info {
    String one, two, three;

    Info(String one, String two, String three) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
        this.three = three;
    }
}
```

И добавление в коллекцию будет наиболее лаконичным

```
public void onClick (View v) {
    info.add(new Info("one", "two", "three"));
}
```